# UICollectionView scroll bug

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have made a full screen collection view with paging turned on:

Here's how I configure it in my code:

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    layout.itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    allQuotesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

And in my Storyboard:

[image: CollectionView setup]

The issue I'm having is when scrolling for the first time screen loaded it has bug in scroll animation:

[image: Animation Bug]

After this bug happens, then scroll becomes smooth.
How can I fix this? I have also used [Github Framework](https://github.com/fahidattique55/FAPaginationLayout) but it didn't help. I need any possible solution to this issue.

Will be grateful for any help, many thanks.

Comment: write you code inside "func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)" with "DispatchQueue.main.async", i hope it's work.

Comment: @AtulParmar I have my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, but I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @AtulParmar Don't need `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` in viewDidAppear

Comment: @VitaliyPoltavets, I think it may problem with load scrollview then view appear, thats why i suggest to wright code inside main thread.

Comment: @AtulParmar following your suggestion did help, but new bug appeared - you can see how collection view layout is being setup. You can see how collection view stretches itself to fit screen size

Comment: @AtulParmar Placed inside `viewWillAppear` - helped a bit, but there's other issue I'm facing - when slide out menu appears my collection view goes back to initial state and scroll progress gets erased

Comment: Set "collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)"

Comment: @AtulParmar Still the same. Bug with scroll disappeared, but when you open screen with this collection view - for 1 sec you can see default layout and then change to a custom layout happens, also when I open side menu - collection view resets to starting `indexPath.item`

Comment: @AtulParmar found issue with resetting `indexPath.item`, now only left is that animation of change

Comment: need a code inside `cellForItem(_ at:)`

Comment: i think you are blocking main thread

Comment: @SPatel to be short - I configure 3 buttons(round corners, corner color) and setup data(images and text you see on gif)

Comment: problem is here `data(images)`

Comment: @SPatel That's how I configure them - `quotesCell.background.image = backgrounds[indexPath.item % backgrounds.count]` I'm using infinite scroll as well

Comment: post code else i can't help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After battling with this trouble for 3 or 4 days finally found reason:

My mistake was here:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let midIndexPath = IndexPath(row: infiniteSize / 2, section: 0)
    allQuotesCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: midIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}
```

After I moved this code into viewDidAppear method - everything started to work and bug disappeared.

So, my final code looks like this right now:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    layout.itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    allQuotesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    allQuotesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    allQuotesCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

    let midIndexPath = IndexPath(row: infiniteSize / 2, section: 0)
    allQuotesCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: midIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {
        UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.allQuotesCollectionView.isHidden = false
        })
    })
}
```

I guess you need to setup collection view after screen has loaded with paging on, mainly starting index.

Hope this will help someone in future!